# How to replace comma separated different values with a particular value

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've a string with the values - 'a','b','c','d,'e'. I need to convert each of the values to the text null - null,null,null,null,null. If there are 10 values in quotes and separated by comma, then 10 null will appear. I tried using REGEXP_REPLACE but failed to get the result.

```
declare
a varchar2(32767) := q'#'a','b','c'#';
c varchar2(32767);
begin
c := replace(REGEXP_REPLACE (a, <don't know what pattern should be here>, 'null'),'''');
dbms_output.put_line(c);
end;
/
```

Comment: REGEX_REPLACE didn't work because you've not specified a regex to use. *I tried REGEX_REPLACE* means you should be able to include something you actually tried.

Comment: thanks for the reply, couln't figure out what pattern should i write there and that was the question i asked.

Comment: Not clear: Why in your attempt you have wrapped the result of `REGEXP_REPLACE` within an additional call to `replace`. What's that for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. For example, you could use the regular expression `'[^,]+'` - which means any number (one or more) of consecutive non-comma characters. Then every occurrence of that pattern will be replaced with the replacement string (while the commas will stay in place).

```
declare
a varchar2(32767) := q'#'a','b','c'#';
c varchar2(32767);
begin
c := REGEXP_REPLACE (a, '[^,]+', 'null');    -- notice the regular expression
dbms_output.put_line(c);
end;
/


null,null,null


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thank you mathGuy, that's the output i needed.